# Can't connect to FTP site because server actively refused it but WinSCP works

Tags: linux, networking, ftp, python, iptables

I have a RedHat 7 server that a friend of mine setup, and he is no longer working here with us, so I have taken over. I can connect to the server and transfer files via WinSCP but I cannot connect to it via the Python script that I wrote. I get the message "failed to connect because the server actively refused it".

After digging around a bit, I did not see anything in the iptables file. It is literally empty, and I don't see any evidence of VSFTPD installed. I was however able to access the firewall setting via GUI and tried playing around with ports with no luck.

I am wondering if the reason its not working via Python is because there is no FTP transfer program installed? Please advise as I am intermediate with my skills in Linux and I am trying to figure this thing out!

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out, in WinSCP you are using SFTP. While ftplib is, as the name says, an FTP library.

For SFTP in Python, use [Paramiko library](https://www.paramiko.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your support Martin, I did find Paramiko after some further investigation!